# format days for joda.time.Days

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using Joda's `daysBetween()` method to compare two dates. When I use this method, it returns a value that has `P` and `D` concatenated to the ends of the day value. For example,

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime notificationDate = new DateTime(qaCase.getFollowUpNotificationDate());
return Days.daysBetween(todaysDate, notificationDate);
```

This is what the method is returning (see image)

[image: value of Days.daysBetween]

I would like it to display just the number. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `getDays()` of the returned `Days` object.

For example,

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime notificationDate = new DateTime(todaysDate).plusDays(5);
Days daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(todaysDate, notificationDate);
System.out.println("Days between = " + daysBetween.getDays());
```

gives the output:

```
Days between = 5
```

See [getDays](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#getDays%28%29) for more information.